# Как оформить заглавие меню?

Tags: css

[image: Желаемый результат]
Cуществует ли вариант оформить заглавие как на картинке серого цвета. Ширина резиновая. Желательно выступающая часть прямоугольника, чтобы была уже за пределами меню, чтобы сэкономить места для строк. Просьба дать наглядный css или объяснить приёмы. Правый треугольник я так понимаю нужно подставить в `background` картинку с высотой 100%?

Comment: я думаю лучший вариант - это весь фон подставить d background. Вобщем стоит сделать картинку

Comment: Так меню резиновое, картинка будет неправильно тянуться, даже если выставить сохранение пропорций.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
body{
  padding: 75px;
}
h3{
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
h3:before,
h3:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
h3:before{
  top: 100%; left: 0;  
  border-width: 0 14px 14px 0;
  border-color: transparent #ACACAC transparent transparent;
}
h3:after{
  top: 0; left: 100%;  
  border-width: 40px 0 0 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ccc;
}
h3:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background: #f00;
}
h3:hover:before{
  border-color: transparent #c00 transparent transparent;
}
h3:hover:after{
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #f00;
}
```

```html
<h3>title</h3>
```

Comment: Благодарю за труд!!! Не совсем подходящий вариант в плане адаптации ширины, флажок вылазит за границу блока меню. В этом плане удачнее наверное будет засунуть SVG в background. А возможно слева добавить прямоугольник, заходящий за рамки блока меню? Наподобие ::before?

Comment: тогда попробуйте так: сделайте обертку и задайте ей padding-right равный ширине правого уголка

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант.

```js
$('.multi-accordion li > a').next().parent().addClass('has-children')

$('.multi-accordion .has-children > a').click(function(e) {
 var li = $(this).parent();
    li.parent('ul').find('.open').add(li).toggleClass('has-children open').children('ul');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.col-left-first {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.multi-accordion-catalog {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.multi-accordion {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #646464;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: none;
}
.multi-accordion ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
.multi-accordion li {
  list-style: none;
}
.multi-accordion > li  > a{
}
.multi-accordion > li  > ul  {
 padding-left: 8px;
}
.multi-accordion > li  > ul > li > ul  {
 padding-left: 8px;
}
.multi-accordion a, 
.multi-accordion a:link, 
.multi-accordion a:visited {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 10px;
  color: #646464;
  position: relative;
}
.multi-accordion  a:hover {
}
.multi-accordion > a:only-child:link, 
.multi-accordion > a:only-child:visited {
  color: blue;
}
.multi-accordion > a:only-child:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: transparent;
}
.multi-accordion-title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.multi-accordion-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  top: 100%; left: -12px;  
  border-width: 0 12px 12px 0;
  border-color: transparent #cccccc transparent transparent;
}
.catalog-title {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.catalog-title:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: -12px; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.catalog-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 40px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #e1e1e1;
}
.has-children,
.open {
  position: relative;
}
.has-children > a:before ,
.open > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  top: 8px;
  right: 4px;
}
.has-children > a:before {
  background: url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/down4-16.png) no-repeat;
}
.open > a:before {
  background: url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mayssam/512/Top_2-16.png) no-repeat;
}
.multi-accordion .open  > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-left-first">
    <div class="multi-accordion-catalog">
        <div class="multi-accordion-title">
            <dt class="catalog-title">Каталог</dt>
        </div>
        <ul class="multi-accordion">
            <li>
                <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a.html">Напольное покрытие</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Паркетная доска</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ламинат</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Пробковые покрытия</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Аксессуары</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1b.html">Тёплый пол</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://agestor.ru/category-id3/category-level1a/category-level2a.html">Инфакрасная плёнка</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Нагревательные маты</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#">Термостаты</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Освещение</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Двери</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```